# Spacing between long amount of text lines css/html/js

Tags: javascript, html, css, line, spacing

Let's say that i have lots of text that i dont want to be in one single huge line, how could i put some white spacings after a certain amount of words? And should i do this in the CSS file or somewhere else?

So for example: this: "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you didnt run into any trouble." to:  "You have succesfully looted the house, as the house was empty you
didnt run into any trouble."

Might not look as great on this site but i think you will get the idea.  The string is empty at first and will be filled by some action that happens on the page.

Comment: Are you looking for `<br />`?

Comment: Dont know if that will work because the string in the html file is empty at first, it will be later filled in by some action on the site.

Comment: Otherwise you could set a width to the element where the text is inside.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick

Comment: For example if you have a `<p>` element. You can give it a class: `<p class="notification">lorem ipsum</p>`. Then in CSS `.notification { width: 50ch }`. You can use other units as well (px, vw, em...). Or you directly give the element a style: `<p style="width: 50ch">`. The ch unit stands for character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a width on the container where your text is inside. It is better to use the `max-width` property since your text may be smaller than the maximal width you want. In this case it is not essential though, since the paragraph is a block element and is full width.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
}

.ch-wrap {
  max-width: 60ch;
}

.px-wrap {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This has no width set</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, doloremque nihil. Illo, veritatis est ipsa cumque culpa praesentium dolor error.</p>
<h1>This has a width of 60 characters</h1>
<p class="ch-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, doloremque nihil. Illo, veritatis est ipsa cumque culpa praesentium dolor error.</p>
<h1>This has a width of 200px set</h1>
<p class="px-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, doloremque nihil. Illo, veritatis est ipsa cumque culpa praesentium dolor error.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use <br> tag to write in a new line. If you want to put white spaces you have to move the text via CSS. For example:

HTML:
`<font id="moving">Some text</font>`

CSS: `#moving { float: right; }`

 but if it not works you can try with:
`#moving { position: absolute !important; float: right; }`
The !important attribute makes sure that the position tag will be set on absolute.